# Monitor log size activity

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How can I get an alert if a file's size stops growing?

```
tail -f mytext.txt
```

show's lines being appended to a file.

```
mail -s "Alert" email@email.com
```

can send an an alert.

I'm a bit lost on how you can combine the two or if there is a more efficient way of monitoring a file's activity.

Comment: What you want to do is a little ambiguous. Do you expect this file to grow constantly non-stop? Most log files aren't *constantly* growing. If not, are you looking for less than a certain number of bytes within a specific time frame?

Comment: you might want to test the log's mtime and alert you if it hasn't been modified in some number of minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way is to do it by cronjob (if interval is more than 1 minute， some systems support interval less than 1 minute), and check md5 value on it only (some systems have md5sum command only, you need adjust)

Enable cronjob, it will run every 10 minutes.

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * bash /FULL_PATH/detect.sh
```

Here is the detect script detect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

file="mytext.txt"

mv /var/tmp/md5OfFile /var/tmp/Oldmd5File
md5 $file > /var/tmp/md5OfFile
# or md5sum $file > /var/tmp/md5OfFile

diff /var/tmp/md5OfFile /var/tmp/Oldmd5File >/dev/null && echo "AAAARGH!" |mailx -s "Alert" email@email.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just simply watch the file size, then record the current size and after an interval of your choice, check the size again and if it's not grown, do your alert. Something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="/tmp/somefile"
size=$(wc -c < "$file")
interval="5"

while true; do
  sleep $interval
  newsize=$(wc -c < "$file")
  if [ $size -ge $newsize ]; then
    echo "AAAARGH!"
  fi
  size="$newsize"
done
```

Replace echo with a mail command or something like that, interval and file with something more reasonable to make this actually work for you.

Comment: don't parse ls, use `size=$(stat -c %s /tmp/somefile)`

Comment: Edits are more than welcome. You might also want to keep in mind that `stat -c` doesn't work in all systems, e.g. Darwin.

Comment: @glennjackman `size=$(wc -c < /tmp/somfile)` also works (and is POSIX)

Comment: @jordanm That won't be as efficient, as it actually has to examine the contents of the file, where `stat` does not.

Comment: @DanFego It doesn't actually read the entire file though. It just seeks to the end.